# How to make a link in aspx reference from app setting value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

need a classic html link reference from app setting value in web.config

```
<a href="<%$appSettings:link%>"+"search.asp" id="more01" title="More" target="_top" >
```

it can not compile

> Parser Error Message: Literal expressions like
>   '<%$appSettings:iframedomain%>' are not allowed. Use " /> instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make it a method or a property of the page in the code-behind, for example:

```
public MyPage: Page
{

    protected string GetLink()
    {
        return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"];
    }

}
```

Then you can bring it through into the markup:

```
<a href="<%= GetLink() %>" id="more01" title="More" target="_top">
```

You could also do:

```
<a href="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["someKey"] %>"+"search.asp" id="more01" title="More" target="_top">
```

But it's a lot less neater IMHO.